# Calculations business hours per day - sql

Tags: sql, pyspark

Good morning,

I have a table where each item has an "initial delivery time" and a "final delivery time." I need to calculate how many working hours each delivery took and then **aggregate (by the final delivery time)** it to see the average working hours my shipments are taking to be delivered each day.

For our business, we consider "business hours from Monday to Friday" as 9 a.m. to 6 p.m. (18:00).

It is possible that the initial time of a shipment is scheduled for any hour outside the business hours. In this case, we must begin counting only when we enter the business hours. For example:

If a shipment's initial delivery is set for Thursday 7 p.m. and the final time ends up being Friday 10 a.m., we should consider only 1 hour (from Friday 9 a.m. to Friday 10 a.m., knowing that from Thursday 7 p.m. to Friday 9 a.m. was outside working hours).

Tried to do the query below - but it doesn’t respect all ours business rules (its not aggregating yet)

Unfortunately here in the office we cannot use “variables” in SQL (we use something called Metabase - what makes it harder

Is anybody up to the challenge of helping me?

> ```
> SELECT 
>     SUM(
>         TIMESTAMPDIFF(
>             HOUR, 
>             GREATEST(data_inicial, TIMESTAMP(DATE(data_inicial), '09:00:00')), 
>             LEAST(data_final, TIMESTAMP(DATE(data_final), '18:00:00'))
>         )
>     ) AS hours
> FROM table
> WHERE WEEKDAY(data_inicial) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
>   AND HOUR(data_inicial) < 18
>   AND WEEKDAY(data_final) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
>   AND HOUR(data_final) >= 9
> UNION
> SELECT 
>     COUNT(*) * 9 AS hours
> FROM table
> WHERE WEEKDAY(data_inicial) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
>   AND HOUR(data_inicial) >= 9
> UNION
> SELECT 
>     COUNT(*) * 9 AS horas_uteis
> FROM table
> WHERE WEEKDAY(data_final) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
>   AND HOUR(data_final) < 18;
> ```

Comment: what should the result look like? should it be grouped by something?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used.)

Comment: @YairMaron - The output should be an amount of average hours per day - (grouped by final delivery day - probably using date_split)

Comment: @jarlh PySpark SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, I think, is well to use calendar table. In example, this calendar table created temporarily as CTE.
You can use permanent table with index,for example  on (date,startH,endH,workDay). That table is easy to maintain. Work calendar is helpful for setting any day attributes, like holidays and etc.

In example aggregate made by the final delivery `date`

See example:

```
with recursive WorkCalendar as( -- work calendar, sufficient for test data
  select 1 n
    ,date('2023-10-23') dt
    ,case when weekday(date('2023-10-23')) between 0 and 4 then 1 else 0 end workDay
    ,case when weekday(date('2023-10-23')) between 0 and 4 then 9 else 0 end startH
    ,case when weekday(date('2023-10-23')) between 0 and 4 then 18 else 0 end endH
    ,weekday(date('2023-10-23')) wd
    ,week(date('2023-10-23')) w
    ,dayname(date('2023-10-23')) dn
union all
  select  n+1
    ,date_add(dt, interval 1 day)  
    ,case when weekday(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) between 0 and 4 then 1 else 0 end workDay
    ,case when weekday(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) between 0 and 4 then 9 else 0 end startH
    ,case when weekday(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) between 0 and 4 then 18 else 0 end endH
    ,weekday(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) wd
    ,week(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) w
    ,dayname(date_add(dt, interval 1 day)) dn
  from WorkCalendar where date_add(dt, interval 1 day)<date('2023-11-23')
)
,ShipmentDt as( -- subquery for to shorten formulas
select * 
  ,hour(data_inicial) h1 ,cast(data_inicial as date) dt1
  ,hour(data_final) h2 ,cast(data_final as date) dt2
from Shipment
)
,ShipmentHours as(
select id,data_inicial,data_final,c.dt,c.workDay,c.startH,c.endH 
     -- hours in data_inicial
      case when dt2>dt1 then  
        endH-case when h1<startH then startH when h1>endH then endH else h1  end
      else -- intraday
        case when h2<startH then startH when h2>endH then endH else h2  end
       -case when h1<startH then startH when h1>endH then endH else h1  end
      end 
    else 0
    end hours_first
    -- hours in data_final
   ,case when dt2>dt1 and c.dt=dt2 then
        case when h2<startH then 0 when h2>endH then (endH-startH) else h2-startH  end
    else 0
    end hours_last
    -- hours in data between (not inculded) data_inicial and data_final
   ,case when c.dt>dt1 and c.dt<dt2 then
        endH-startH
    else 0
    end hours_inter
from ShipmentDt sd
left join WorkCalendar c on c.dt>=sd.dt1 and c.dt<=sd.dt2
)
,ShipmentWorkHours as( -- total work hours for shipment
select id,min(data_inicial) data_inicial,min(data_final)data_final
  ,sum((hours_first+hours_last+hours_inter)*workDay) as totH
from ShipmentHours
group by id
)
,AvgDelivery as( -- average work hours, delivered in date - target task
select cast(data_final as date) data_final, avg(totH) avgH,count(*) cnt
from ShipmentWorkHours
group by cast(data_final as date)
)
,ActiveShipments as( -- additional - count of active shipments by date
select dt,count(*) cnt
from ShipmentHours
group by dt
)
,ActiveDeliveryByDate as( -- additional - active shipments list for date
select dt,id,data_inicial,data_final
from ShipmentHours
where dt=cast('2023-10-25' as date)
)
 select * from AvgDelivery
-- select * from ActiveShipments
-- select * from ActiveDeliveryByDate
-- select * from ShipmentWorkHours
```

Query result with sample data

| data_final | avgH | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-23 | 9.0000 | 3 |
| 2023-10-26 | 14.8000 | 5 |
| 2023-10-27 | 17.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-10-24 | 8.6667 | 6 |
| 2023-10-28 | 36.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-10-29 | 37.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-10-30 | 46.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-10-31 | 55.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-11-05 | 82.0000 | 1 |
| 2023-11-06 | 90.0000 | 1 |

ActiveShipments example

| dt | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-23 | 15 |
| 2023-10-26 | 12 |
| 2023-10-25 | 11 |
| 2023-10-27 | 7 |
| 2023-10-24 | 12 |
| 2023-10-28 | 6 |
| 2023-10-29 | 5 |
| 2023-10-30 | 4 |
| 2023-10-31 | 3 |
| 2023-11-05 | 2 |
| 2023-11-04 | 2 |
| 2023-11-03 | 2 |
| 2023-11-02 | 2 |
| 2023-11-01 | 2 |
| 2023-11-06 | 1 |

ActiveShipmnetsByDate example

| dt | id | data_inicial | data_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25 | 14 | 2023-10-25 11:00:00 | 2023-10-26 13:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 15 | 2023-10-25 11:00:00 | 2023-10-26 18:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 16 | 2023-10-25 11:00:00 | 2023-10-26 20:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 17 | 2023-10-25 11:00:00 | 2023-10-26 16:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 18 | 2023-10-25 09:00:00 | 2023-10-26 17:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 33 | 2023-10-23 19:00:00 | 2023-10-28 19:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 34 | 2023-10-23 17:00:00 | 2023-10-29 19:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 35 | 2023-10-23 17:00:00 | 2023-10-30 19:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 36 | 2023-10-23 17:00:00 | 2023-10-31 19:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 37 | 2023-10-23 17:00:00 | 2023-11-05 19:00:00 |
| 2023-10-25 | 38 | 2023-10-23 17:00:00 | 2023-11-06 17:00:00 |

WorkCalendar example

| n | dt | workDay | startH | endH | wd | w | dn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-23 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 0 | 43 | Monday |
| 2 | 2023-10-24 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 1 | 43 | Tuesday |
| 3 | 2023-10-25 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 2 | 43 | Wednesday |
| 4 | 2023-10-26 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 3 | 43 | Thursday |
| 5 | 2023-10-27 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 4 | 43 | Friday |
| 6 | 2023-10-28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 43 | Saturday |
| 7 | 2023-10-29 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 44 | Sunday |
| 8 | 2023-10-30 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 0 | 44 | Monday |

For demo, I'll use sample data

```
Create table Shipment (id int,data_inicial datetime,data_final datetime);
insert into Shipment values
 (11,'2023-10-23 09:00:00','2023-10-23 17:00:00')
,(12,'2023-10-23 08:00:00','2023-10-23 12:00:00')
,(13,'2023-10-23 08:00:00','2023-10-23 19:00:00')
,(14,'2023-10-25 11:00:00','2023-10-26 13:00:00')
,(15,'2023-10-25 11:00:00','2023-10-26 18:00:00')
,(16,'2023-10-25 11:00:00','2023-10-26 20:00:00')
,(17,'2023-10-25 11:00:00','2023-10-26 16:00:00')
,(18,'2023-10-25 09:00:00','2023-10-26 17:00:00')
,(19,'2023-10-26 09:00:00','2023-10-27 17:00:00')
,(21,'2023-10-23 08:00:00','2023-10-24 17:00:00')
,(22,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-10-24 17:00:00')
,(23,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-10-24 19:00:00')
,(24,'2023-10-23 19:00:00','2023-10-24 09:00:00')
,(31,'2023-10-23 19:00:00','2023-10-24 17:00:00')
,(32,'2023-10-23 19:00:00','2023-10-24 17:00:00')
,(33,'2023-10-23 19:00:00','2023-10-28 19:00:00')
,(34,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-10-29 19:00:00')
,(35,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-10-30 19:00:00')
,(36,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-10-31 19:00:00')
,(37,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-11-05 19:00:00')
,(38,'2023-10-23 17:00:00','2023-11-06 17:00:00')
;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7_iG0ZXl)